# gdata calendar 2.0 Appointment support

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I'm playing around with the gdata-calendar-2.0.jar library.  So far I'm very impressed.  I'm trying to use the [Appointment Slot functionality](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=190998) that's offered through calendar.  However, I'm not finding any of this in the jar?  Does anyone know if this has been ported to the java library yet?  I really don't want this to be a deal breaker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're interested in using the Google Calendar API, I'd *strongly* suggest using [v3](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/), as prior versions are deprecated. Appointment slots functionality isn't currently available within any version of the API, and I don't know if it will be, but it definitely will not be supported in v2 or prior.

Comment: Thanks, btw.  I wasn't aware of the v3 library.  I was seeing some odd exceptions coming back from the server using certain calls which hopefully the new library will clean up.